# phpbb session across folders

Tags: php, session, phpbb

I'm using a phpBB (2.0.22) in a website, located at myWebSite.com/forum

I am creating some other pages in myWebSite.com/otherForders

What I want, is to check whether a person in logged into myWebSite.com/forum when they are in myWebSite.com/otherForders

Wondering if that's possible.

I've tried `session_start(); print_r($_SESSION);` in myWebSite.com/otherForders/index.php and all I get is `Array ( )` (an empty array).

Anyone with a solution?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should integrate your board with your code

Here is sample ::

```
define('IN_PHPBB', true);
$phpbb_root_path = './';
include($phpbb_root_path . 'extension.inc');
include($phpbb_root_path . 'common.'.$phpEx);

//
// Start session management
//
$userdata = session_pagestart($user_ip, PAGE_INDEX);
init_userprefs($userdata);
//
// End session management
//
```

Then use

$userdata['username'], $userdata['user_id'] & etc.
$userdata has array with values from users_table for your board for logged in user.

Comment: Thanks @Alex Emilov, this tend to work somewhat, but I'm getting [username] => Anonymous

Comment: Well, I code mostly phpBB3 and I'm not sure about this integration, I downloaded a fresh copy of phpBB2 and looked at some pages and it seems that to be the code.Maybe we miss something with authentication.Are you sure, you are logged in? I will install 2.0.22 and post again.

Comment: I've installed it and tested and it seems to work that way.
First are you sure, you have correct specified path for file see $phpbb_root_path = './'; (you may have error_reporting 0 and for that we don't have result) and the second issue is that you need SID parameter in url.Copy your sid link from you forum index and paste in the url of the new file.

index.php?sid=a90814a1fb6f8ce49f1bb6edde9f839b => test.php?sid=a90814a1fb6f8ce49f1bb6edde9f839b

Comment: Well, there is surely a problem. I'm logged in when i'm in site.com/forum/index.php. However, when I create a site.com/forum/test.php with the data you wrote above, I get [user_id] => -1 PS. Thanks for the attempt friend.

Comment: Yes, tried everything. The path is correct, else it will give me error (error reporting is 1). Tried copying sid as well

Comment: wait, it is working it seems. I tried now in FF. Earlier, I was working with Chrome

Comment: Finally it's working, strange that it doesn't work in Chrome, but only in FF.

Answer (score 1):

The session variable will not accessible in this way. The session cookie of your phpbb is stored at `myWebSite.com/forum` and when you visit pages out of `forum` directory ie `(otherForders)` the session of `myWebSite.com/forum` will not available there and a new session will be stared which is obviously a blank array until you assign some values and session cookie for this session is stored at `myWebSite.com/otherForders`.

You have to tell php to save session on root domain which is `myWebSite.com` so that session will be available in all other directories.

You could do this with `ini_set`.

You have to put `ini_set` before the `session_start()` is called. I don't know about `phpbb` if they give any admin interface to change the session cookie domain value. You should check if phpbb provides this.

`ini_set('session.cookie_domain','.myWebSite.com');`

you could also try

```
session_set_cookie_params(0, '/', '.myWebSite.com');
session_start();
```

Comment: Thanks @Shakti Singh, where to use the `ini_set('session.cookie_domain','.myWebSite.com');` part please?

Comment: you should call it before `session_start()`

Comment: @Jeremy: Because your phpbb session is still on the domain `mywebsite.com/forum`. That should also be at `mywebsite.com`

Comment: Thanks, the phpbb structure is complicated, I didn't even find where they are doing their session_start() using a DW search. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I even tried creating a test.php in mywebsite.com/forum/ to see how sessions appearing there with `session_start(); print_r($_SESSION);` and I'm getting an empty array there as well. Weird.